# Recommended file sizes for web

Tags: web-optimization

I am doing a web performance optimization using YSlow and Page Speed recomendations but when it comes to file sizes neither says anything about it.

Does anybody knows where I can get some recomendation of the max size of some file types??
For example images shouldn't be greater than XXX KB or something like that.
But i need reliable sources not just suggestions. I mean XXX did some research and they recommend this or that.

Comment: At the risk of making this question too local, it really depends on what part of the world most of your users are in.  The recommendations for North America and Western Europe will be vastly different than the recommendations for say South Africa.

Comment: I am actually in Latin America :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never stumble on any recommendations rather than common sense. A lot of small size files create a chatter, big files slow you down and can time-out. It really is what performance tuning is for - run your tests for your particular setup, there's no magic bullet

Answer (score 1):

When I first did web development (1998) Australia our recommended limit for the entire page size (including images) was 40 kB (who was that laughing?).

The scary thing is that for accessability, we still have to worry about dial-up users and so try to keep to this if we can (exploiting client side caching where possible).